# echo value back in php backend source code

Tags: php, post, curl, printing, echo

I have an audio player that looks for a folder path to get its audio files, but it doesn't work when we supply it with an `ECHO`,`$_POST`, `$_GET`, `print_r`,`$_REQUEST`, or `$_SESSION`, in the source code, it absolutely wants a real final path string to work. So I need a way to convert my `$_POST` variable into a real path in the source code. Now keep in my mind that my $_POST variable does echo a different path for each user, like this:

> mysite.com/user-1234/

Now I have this code:

```
$path = $_POST['something'];// this does not work, no other functions or variable works.
```

What I need is this:

```
$path = "mysite.com/user-1234/"; //this works, only the real path works.
```

How can I manage to have: `$path =  $_POST['something'];` already converted to a real visible path like this in the source code:

> $path = mysite.com/user-1234/

Comment: what do you want to do ? add more information and code since that much information you provided is not enough ... and btw echo , print are not variable

Comment: note that $_POST is array so `$path = $_POST` is probably wrong and should by something like `$path = $_POST['path_from_somewhere']`

Comment: Also please note that without some serious sanity checks, which from the tone of your question, I doubt you have considered, any attempt to work out file paths that contain user input is dangerous

Comment: Remember, the first load is a GET request, the second request is POST. try print_r($_POST); ?> and look request. Check your html form. Post more code.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, but the system does the POST itself from the backend to the player, there is no user input in the POST.

Comment: Can you show the 'backend' code that does the POST?

Comment: Thansk WHK, print_r doesn't work either, I just edited my question.

Comment: Hi Sean, The backend code is a whole CMS script that only send the user folder path to the player plug-in in a POST, for the player to load its audio files. so it's a bit complicated to send tons of php files here. I know my question is tricky, but I also know there is a simple solution :-)